# I dont know what to do

Tags: statements

```
public MyTime nextSecond()
 {
  if(getSecond()>=0||getSecond()<=58)
   return new MyTime(getHour(),getMinute(),getSecond()+1);
  else if(getSecond()==59)
   return new MyTime(getHour(),getMinute(),0);
  else
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Second!");
 }

 public MyTime nextMinute()
 {
  if(getMinute()>=0||getMinute()<=58)
   return new MyTime(getHour(),getMinute()+1,0);
  else if(getMinute()==59)
   return new MyTime(getHour()+1,0,0);
  else
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Minute!");
 }


 public MyTime nextHour()
 {
  if(getHour()>=0||getHour()<=22)
   return new MyTime(getHour()+1,0,0);
  else if(getHour()==23)
   return new MyTime(0,0,0);
  else
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Hour!");
 }
}
```

I am a new programmer and this is my code, it doesn't have any errors but if statements are not executing!

Does anyone know why it isn't working?

Comment: How are you calling the methods?

Comment: You should carefully re-think what conditions you want to test and check what conditions you actually test in the first if statement of each method.

Comment: Might want to rephrase the question, I don't know what to do is very broad.

Answer (score 2):

In if condition if the first statement is correct and the extra conditional is combined with OR then it return true although the second condition is false 
it shouldn't be OR statement between conditions it should be AND

Answer (score 1):

You are using logical OR where you should be using logical AND.

For example this:

```
if (getSecond() >= 0 || getSecond() <= 58)
```

should be

```
if (getSecond() >= 0 && getSecond() <= 58)
```

In your version if the value returned by `getSecond()` is 59 it will never reach the `else if` because the first if statement will evaluate `getSecond() > 0` to `true` and because it is logical OR, it will not evaluate the second logical expression in that condition (`getSecond() <= 58`).

The same goes for minutes and hours.